# How do I store a range of cells in a variable

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently working on a Sudoku program as a project in excel using VBA and I need to store a Range of cells in a variable.

Something along the lines of this:

```
'''
dim grid as string 

grid = range("b3:j11")
'''
```

But I'm not sure what to dim grid as.
I've tried integer, string and range but grid never seems to have a value.
I'm also assuming I'm not assigning the range to the variable correctly

/////////////////////////////////

Following the replies im pasting the code here.
The duplicatecheck function looks through a range of cells to check if their are more than one of a certain number and then highlight the cells accordingly

As i want to look through a different range of cells for different checks i need to make the range a variable so the function can be reused

however when the variable grid is called in the duplicatecheck function it has no value and theirfor no cells are being checked

```
Dim row As Integer

Dim col As Integer

Dim grid As Variant

Dim checkmark As Integer


Sub Rowcheck()

    checkmark = 1
    row = 0
    col = 0

    grid = range("b3:j3").Value

    For row = 0 To 8

        duplicatecheck

    Next row
```

End Sub

```
Function duplicatecheck()

Dim safe As Boolean

Dim check As Integer

Dim x As Integer

        ' check each number in a range for duplicates starting with 1
For check = 1 To 9
    If Application.Worksheet.Function.CountIf(Selection.Offset(row, col), range(grid)).check = 1      Then 
' if number is only found once
safe = True
    ElseIf Application.Worksheet.Function.CountIf(Selection.Offset(row, col), range(grid)).check < 1 Then
' if the number is found less than once in the range
safe = False
    ElseIf Application.Worksheet.Function.CountIf(Selection.Offset(row, col), range(grid)).check > 1 Then
' if the number is found more than once
Selection.Offset(row, x).range(grid).Interior.colour = vbBlue ' highlight the range red

        If checkmark = 1 Then
              For x = 0 To 8
                    Selection.Offset(row, x).range(geid).Value = check
                    Selection.Offset(row, x).range.ont.colour = vbRed
               Next x
        ElseIf checkmark = 2 Then
              For x = 0 To 8
                    Selection.Offset(x, col).range(grid).Value = check
                    Selection.Offset(x, col).range.ont.colour = vbRed

              Next x
              safe = False
                 error = True

    If safe = False Then
       complete = False
    End If
```

End If
   End If
 Next check
End Function

Comment: Ive tried both this code and Rons but neither seem to be working.

after running the code with grid set as range or variant after the grid or set grid = range("b3:j11") the variable grid still doesnt have a value when called later on

Comment: Check my comment in Ron's answer. Variants can store either ranges or values. If you're trying to store values, use the value of the range, not the range itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store it in a variant

```
Dim vGrid as Variant
vGrid = range("B3:J11")
```

vGrid will then be a 2D 1-based array, with Dim 1 = rows and Dim2 = columns

eg the contents of B3 would be in vGrid(1,1)

**Edit:** It seems you are now using Grid as a string argument to the Range object and having problems with your CountIF.

Set **Option Explicit** and the option to require variable declaration as I mentioned in a comment.

So far as your CountIF statement, if the range you are checking is that declared in Grid, and your criteria is in Selection.Offset(row,col), then the line should look something like:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(grid),Selection.Offset(Row, col)) = 1 Then ...
```

Note that I have corrected your using Function as a property of the Worksheet object; put the range and criteria arguments in the proper order; and removed the .check you had added at the end of that function.

Comment: Ive set set grid as a variant and ran the code '   grid = range("b3:j11")    ' but when the variable grid is called later on  it still doesn't have a value

Comment: Use `vGrid = Range("B3:J11").Value` instead. This should store the range's *values* instead of the range itself. There's a massive difference in *storing a range* and *storing a range's value/s* in a variable.

Comment: @user2920648 If the sheet on which that range is populated is not ActiveSheet, you will need to specify the worksheet.  If that doesn't work, post more of your code

Comment: @Nanashi Since the value property is the default property of the Range object, there is no difference in behavior when adding .Value to the Range.

Comment: I will claim no mastery of the inner workings of VBA, but I beg to differ. `Variant` can store many types of variables -- ranges, sheets, integers, strings, dates, etc. The one thing that sticks out is: if you store a range inside a variant, it's still a range. I know that `.Value` is its default property, but that doesn't mean that you should store it as such. In cases dealing with variants, you have to be very implicit with your assignments, or some odd behavior is bound to happen. Note that I'm not opposing your answer, btw. It just seems like OP is confused with his terminology. :)

Comment: Thank you for trying to help but i still cant seem to get it working, ive posted my code above, please help

Comment: @Nanashi If you want to store just the Values in a Variant array, then you can do it as I've shown.  If you want to store the entire range object(s), then you need to use the Set method.  In that case, if grid is a variant, then it will wind up being of type Variant/Object/Range.  Of course, if you want the entire range object, it is simpler to just declare a variable of Type Range.

Comment: @user2920648 Using my method, the values in B3:J3 are being stored in grid(1,1) to grid(1,9). duplicatecheck function has a number of errors. You should start by explicitly declaring all variables, and enforce that by putting Option Explicit at the start (in the VBE menu select Tools/Options Editor: Require Variable Declaration. You should also note that the syntax for your CountIf is wrong: Range(grid) is meaningless (check the allowed arguments for the Range object). There is no .check property of the Countif function. I'll try to post a working version of what I think you are trying to do.

Comment: @user2920648 Well, I'm not really sure of your algorithm, so cannot post a working copy. In any event, if you want to just store the Values in B3:J3 in grid, use it as I showed before; if you want to set up a Range Object equivalent to B3:J3, then you need to use the Set method; and you can declare 'grid' as being of type Range

Comment: im sorry for lack of experience. @Ron the statement Range(grid) is what i need to change depending on what range of cells i need checked, eg for one check it needs to be a row and on a different check it would be a column. which is why i was thinking i could use a variable. it seemed possible as VBA didnt give me any errors or complain at me for having the wrong syntax.

i really appreciate the help this one small thing would make the whole macro work

Comment: @user2920648 Well, don't forget that for the CountIF function, the range is the first argument, and the criteria is the second argument.

Comment: for example the range for a row would be ("b3:j3")
but a column would be ("b3:b11"). 

So what i want to do is set the value of the variable grid to one of  the cell ranges before running the duplicatecheck. that way the range can be changed without repeating huge chunks of code

Comment: @user2920648 Then something like Set grid = Range(xxx): DuplicateCheck

Comment: i still cant get  it to work :/ . as youve pointed out i may have the syntax for the countif and range(grid) wrong. is there a different way i could write that statement?

Comment: @user2920648 I don't know what you are doing now. See my addition to my answer.

Comment: @ShyamSundarShankar I really can't infer exactly what you want to do from your comment. Possibly you'd need to loop through the array to create your text file; or maybe there's another way.  I suggest you try it, write some code and then, if it doesn't work for you, post a new question indicating the problem.  Please also read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)